# dart confusion on parameterized List

Tags: dart

Why this code no raise an error?

```dart
List<String> x;

void main() {
  x = [1,23,3,423,2];
  print(x);
}
```

Sorry for the newbie question, but i just start learning dart, and i ask this because of my understanding that the `x` can only contain a list of`String` and should raise an exception due to the value not a list of `String` but a list of `num`. This is a bug, or?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is optional typing in action.

```dart
var x; // same as List<String> x
List<String> y;

main() {
  x = [1,2,3,4];
  y = x; // valid
  x = y; // valid
  print(x); // [1,2,3,4]
  print(y); // [1,2,3,4]
}
```

Whether you specify `List<String>` or `var`, your code will execute the same.  The type annotations (`List<String>`) are used by the tools to verify your code.

A good article to read on the dartlang site is one about [optional types](http://www.dartlang.org/articles/optional-types/).

**Edit:** Actually, this is also an interesting point about Lists.  If you initialize a list using a literal list( eg, `[]`), then you are actually creating a `List()`, eg:

```dart
main() {
  var x = new List(); 
  var y = [];
  print(x is List); // true
  print(y is List); // true
}
```

If, however, you want a typed list using generics, you must use the constructor syntax, eg:

```dart
main() {
  var x = new List<String>();
  print(x is List); // true
  print(x is List<String>); // true
  print(x is List<num>); // false
}
```

Comment: Just an addition: you can also write like this: `var foo = <String>['foo', 'bar'];`. :)

Comment: Thanks - I forgot that variant!

Answer (score 0):

Dart types are optional not static. So on runtime all type annonations is essentially replaced with `var`