# Dart extend WebSocket

Tags: websocket, dart

I'm trying to add a field to WebSockets by extending the class. I don't receive errors while compiling but when I try to assign the field I get a 'no such method: myCustomString' error. Snippet below. Any help is appreciated.

```dart
class WebSocketConnection2 extends WebSocketConnection {
  String myCustomString = "";
}
```

...Usage

```dart
wsHandler.onOpen = (WebSocketConnection2 conn) {
conn.onMessage = (data) {
  var event = data['aString'];
  switch (event) {
    case 'someCase':
      conn.myCustomString = nName; // This line throw the error.
      ...
      break;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be because the implementation class of the `wsHandler` is passing a `WebSocketConnection` instance.  It doesn't know about your `WebSocketConnection2` class.

You'll need to provide your own implementation of the `wsHandler` to use the `WebSocketConnection2` class.

Note: although you have specified `wsHandler.onOpen = (WebSocketConnection2 conn) {` this is interpreted by dart as `wsHandler.onOpen = (conn) {` - this is optional typing in action.

Comment: This might be a useful post to read re optional types: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14361895/dart-confusion-on-parameterized-list/14362114#14362114